# An error in executing a .gap file in GAP software

Tags: algebra, gap-system

I am trying to load two .gap files but I receive the following error message. What could be the reason?

Thanks a lot in advance.

[Error in executing .gap files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNNIx.jpg)

I have already read F1.gap file. I don't understand why it says F1 must be readable to load the F2.gap file.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This is actually a question more suitable for GAP Support (see links [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gap/info)). Anyhow, do you execute the first command, and then the 2nd, or you paste both (so actually the error message appears after the 1st one?) Why there are so many spaces around F1 and F2? Does the problem vanish if the path does not contain spaces (e.g. rename the directory to `CayleyGraphs` or `Cayley_Graphs`)?

Comment: Please consider asking questions (with relevant mathematical context) on GAP [here on Mathematics Q&A site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap). Also, important to learn how to copy text from Windows and then include it in your question as *text*, indented by 4 spaces for the code formatting. Then people who are trying to reply may copy and paste it into GAP. A screenshot does not allow to do this, and is not indexed for search.